# Capturing print output into a vector

Tags: r

I want to capture the output of a for loop into a vector so it can be plotted.  A simple example is as follows:

```
for(i in 3:5) {
    z <- i + 1
    print(z)
}
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

How can I capture the output of 4,5,6 so it can be plotted?

Comment: Maybe you could give us a better overview of what you're trying to achieve. Andrie's suggestions are good, but without knowing what you're trying to do, we might as well shoot into the dark.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a `for` loop and printing values, a better idiom is to use `sapply` (or `lapply`):

```
sapply(3:5, function(i)i+1)
[1] 4 5 6
```

If, for some reason, you can't use a member of the `apply` family, then you can modify your loop to assign the output value of your function to a vector:

```
z <- vector("numeric", 3)
for(i in 3:5) { z[i-2] <- i + 1 }
z
[1] 4 5 6
```

---

In very rare cases it may be useful to actually capture the output of `print`:

```
z <- vector("numeric", 3)
for(i in 3:5) { z[i-2] <- capture.output(print(i + 1)) }
z
[1] "[1] 4" "[1] 5" "[1] 6"
```

But you'll notice that this captures all of the output of `print`, including the vector information.  You can get rid of some of this by using `cat`:

```
z <- vector("numeric", 3)
for(i in 3:5) { z[i-2] <- capture.output(cat(i + 1)) }
z
[1] "4" "5" "6"
```

Now you have a character vector, and will have to do some cleanup.

### The bottom line

Don't try to capture the output of `print` in a loop.  Use `sapply` or `lapply`.